# How to repeat animation background image in body tag?

Tags: html, css, animation

Hi I m try so many times and search to Google not finding best solution

Can u help me

My question is How to repeat all times animation background image in body tag in html

My code is this

**HTML**

```
<div class="loader">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
/*Lets start with the flower animationr*/
.loader {
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
z-index:-1;
}
.loader span {
display: inline-block;
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
margin: -280px 40px 54px -34px;
background:url("http://ppus.techletsolutions.com/media/wysiwyg/home/bg-leaves-19may14.png");
/*background:url("http://premiumcoding.com/CSSTricks/fallingLeaves/leaf.png");*/
-webkit-animation: loader 25s infinite  linear;
-moz-animation: loader 25s infinite  linear;
}
.loader span:nth-child(5n+5) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
.loader span:nth-child(3n+2) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.loader span:nth-child(2n+5) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
-moz-animation-delay: 1.7s;
}

.loader span:nth-child(3n+10) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 2.7s;
-moz-animation-delay: 2.7s;
}
.loader span:nth-child(7n+2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.loader span:nth-child(4n+5) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5.5s;
-moz-animation-delay: 5.5s;
}
.loader span:nth-child(3n+7) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
-moz-animation-delay: 8s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader {
0% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
}
75% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 900px) rotateZ(270deg);
}
100% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 1100px) rotateZ(360deg);
}
}
@-moz-keyframes loader {
0% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 1;
-moz-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
}
75% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 1;
-moz-transform: transform: translate(0px, 900px) rotateZ(270deg);
}
100% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 0;
-moz-transform: translate(0px, 1100px) rotateZ(360deg);
}
}
/* Lets start with the flower animationr*/
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/UUC57/)**

Answer (score 1):

try to loop it so that at the end items end up in starting position
at 0% start, at 99%go to end, at 100% go to start, and do some css stylings to not show 99-100 phase.

```
0% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
}
99% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 600px) rotateZ(360deg);
}
100% {
width: 141px;
height: 191px;
opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UUC57/3/
*p.s. sorry i would rather comment this but my reputation is lower than 50*
**update:** issue was just in mistype of original jsfiddle at line 79
`-moz-transform: transform: translate(0px, 900px) rotateZ(270deg);` 2 transforms try http://jsfiddle.net/UUC57/4/

Comment: if you mean they must fall from sky ^, add this to .loader{top:-200px;} this will hide original position of flowers so only falling phase will be shown(0%<x - 99%), http://jsfiddle.net/UUC57/6/